# When I try to modify a question the system says "Nothing appears to have changed."

Tags: support, tags

I trying to edit a question: [What is the best way to add Jquery to my drupal site without building modules and keeping it cut and paste?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182786/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-jquery-to-my-drupal-site-without-building-modules-an) and when I add the tag [jquery](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jquery) and go to Save Edits the system says:

> Nothing appears to have changed.

The original question:

[image]

When I try to add a tag:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jquery is a synonym of javascript, so actually nothing changed because jquery was automatically replaced by javascript in the tags.

Comment: I think that this is not correct, one question related to the jquery configuration is not a question related to javascript.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer The synonym does seem to be a bit problematic, but that is an entirely different question.

Comment: In this case I think that jquery don't should be show in the tags available or at least available with a message indicating the situation.

Comment: I think javascript is the right tag - we don't encourage jQuery-specific questions because they're off topic. If a question is about Drupal's JS API, javascript is sufficient for tagging in my opinion. If it also needs jQuery, there's a good chance it's a question for Stack Overflow

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I agree with Clive - "question related to the jquery configuration" is probably not Drupal specific enough to be on-topic here. And Drupal's JS ecosystem is jQuery based, so anything JS in Drupal is also jQuery-related.

Comment: thanks, I learning from yours comments

Answer (score 1):

Mad Scientist explained why you are getting that error message. Clive and Mołot explained that jQuery questions are off-topic for us.

The reason why [jquery](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jquery) is marked as synonym of [javascript](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) on *Drupal Answers* are essentially two:

- On *Drupal Answers*, those two tags are synonyms, which means that a question about using jQuery on Drupal is for us a normal question about JavaScript. This doesn't mean that for other sites those tags are synonyms; that is quite not true on Stack Overflow where, anyway, a question about plain JavaScript will get the _jquery_tag removed.
- The synonym has been set to avoid keeping to edit questions that use [jquery](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jquery). This includes questions migrated from other sites.

Comment: thanks for the info ;-)